# select items from a list relate to indexes saved in other list?

Tags: c#, list

i have:
a list of list x;
a list of list A that contains indexces of some elements in list d as A[i]= [1,3]
a list of list d that contains values as d[i]=[500,200,1000, 40,60,..]
i want to select from d elements which has the indexes saved in A and add them to x
then x[0] will = [200,40]

i use this code:

```
List<int> sublist = new List<int>();
for (int b = 0; b < A[i1].Count(); b++)
{
    sublist .Add(d[i1][A[i1][b]]);
 }
x.Add(sublist );
```

can you help me to do it with an efficient methode?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> sublist = new List<int>();
foreach(int i in A)
{
    sublist.Add(d[i]);
}
x.Add(sublist);
```

Comment: x is a list of list, it needs to add sub list to x first and add elements to x[last] as I did up , I hope I can find a more performance method using linque

Comment: Edited my answer. That should be it, as you're describing it. It's not that hard nor so heavy as performance. But you should take Richard's answer into account.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you mean by "efficient".

If you want the fastest execution time, then nested `for` loops will probably be your best bet. You might be able to save some time by specifying the initial size for `sublist` to match the number of elements in `A[i1]`, and by dropping the `.Count()` extension method in favour of the `.Count` or `.Length` property, depending on the precise types you're using.

If you just want simple code, then LINQ can help:

```
List<List<int>> x = A
    .Select((value, index) => value.Select(i => d[index][i]).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ERNKpq)

Or:

```
List<List<int>> x = A
    .Zip(d, (ai, di) => ai.Select(i => di[i]).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LaWoXb)